# How do I use non capturing groups in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, regex, regexextract

This is what I intend to do.
[image]

But a similar one doesn't work.
[image]

As with any problem I post, I still can't solve it after more than two hours of trying. :-(

https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax

Comment: Please avoid providing just an image in your questions. Images cannot be properly indexed by search engines (like Google or SE). Edit your question writing both the formulas you have tried and the expected results as found [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/136307) or [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/136317). Even better please read how to and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped.

Comment: What would the result you are after look like, in other words, what exactly is it you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Try:
`={REGEXEXTRACT(D2,"ing?"),REGEXEXTRACT(D2,"ziggo")}`

Your example in the question can be written as follows:

`={REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"banana"),REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"berry")}`